Conda not working on WSL Ubuntu
I've installed Anaconda via the file Anaconda3-2024.02-1-Linux-x86_64 provided on their website to my /home/user/anaconda3 folder.
Installation seems to be ok, running the conda init command too. The .bashrc file has been modified.
Unfortunatelly after sourcing .bashrc, restarting shell or trying to activate any environment (either base or created one) I end up with:
CondaError: Run 'conda init' before 'conda activate'
It does so since installation. I am running WSL2 Ubuntu on Windows 11.

Solved by:

~/anaconda3/bin/conda init --reverse --all
Remove any anaconda related folders from where you installed, for example:
sudo rm -rf ~/anaconda3
sudo rm -rf ~/miniconda3
Make sure not to have any aliases named conda in .bashrc
Install Anaconda from source once again.

